# Need help with the proof of a theorem about Gaussian integers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Theorem 6-3. If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are integers of $Z[i]$, and $\beta \neq 0$ then there are $\kappa$ and $\rho$ in $Z[i]$ such that
$$\alpha =\beta\kappa+\rho, \text{      } N_\rho < N_\beta$$

Proof: Since $\beta \neq 0 $, we can write
$$\frac{\alpha}{\beta}=\frac{a+bi}{c+di}=\frac{(a+bi)(c-di)}{c^2+d^2}=A+Bi$$

Where A and B are rational numbers, not necessarily integers. Let x and y be rational integers nearest to A and B, respectively, so that

$$|A-x| \leq 1/2$$
$$|B-y| \leq 1/2$$
(Why do we have to use the latter? Where does the 1/2 come from?, why do we need to get close to A and B?)

Then
$|\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-(x+yi)|=|(A-x)+ (\beta -y)i|=((A-x)^2+(\beta-y)^2)^{1/2} \leq (1/4+1/4)^{1/2} < 1$

(Here I don't understand how the following is true: $|(A-x)+ (\beta -y)i|=((A-x)^2+(\beta-y)^2)^{1/2}) $ why do we use absolute value and how does that relate to the norm?

Hence, if we set
$$x+yi= \kappa \quad \alpha - \beta(x+yi)=\rho$$

(why? I understand that would satisfy the expression above but it's looks weird)

then

$$N_\rho=N(\alpha -\kappa\beta)=N_\beta*N(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-\kappa)<N_\beta$$

I understand we did all that previous stuff to show that $N(\alpha/\beta-\kappa)<1$, so it would squeeze the factor $N_{\beta}$, but I don't see how this is true in what we did.

I need a  more detailed explanation about the proof. That would be awesome.

Comment: Firstly, by the definition of the field norm, $N(a+bi)=(a+bi)(a-bi)=a^2+b^2=|a+bi|^2$.  Secondly, if $x\in \mathbb{R}$, let $n$ be the smallest integer greater than $x$. If $|x-n|\leq 1/2$, we are done. If not, $|x-(n-1)|\leq 1/2$. Thirdly, we make $|A-x|\leq 1/2$ and $|B-y|\leq 1/2$ to force to have $|\alpha/\beta - (x+yi)|<1$, so that $|\alpha - (x+yi)\beta|^2<|\beta|^2$. This means that $\alpha=(x+yi)\beta + (\alpha - (x+yi)\beta)$ and $N(\alpha - (x+yi)\beta)< N(\beta)$. So we know that $N$ is a Euclidean function. It is just a proof strategy. If you don't see how it works, try to apply ..

Comment: the same argument on $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$.

Comment: $4/5 \in R$ and $1-4/5 \neq 1/2$

Comment: $|1-4/5|\leq 1/2$

Comment: I'd think to the lattice $\beta \mathbb{Z}[i]$ generated by $\beta$. It is just a rotated version of the lattice $|\beta|\, \mathbb{Z}[i]$. And clearly, for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$, its distance to such a lattice is $< |\beta|$, i.e. there is a point of the lattice $\beta \kappa $ such that $|\alpha -\beta \kappa| < |\beta|$, squaring both side you have that $N(\rho) < N(\beta)$

Comment: @TheMathNoob Also, saying $N(\alpha/\beta-\kappa)$ isn't exactly accurate, since $N$ has domain $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, whereas $\alpha/\beta-\kappa$ could be anything in $\mathbb{Q}[i]$.  You should instead say $|\alpha/\beta-\kappa|^2$

Answer (score 1):

"Why do we have to use the latter? Where does the 1/2 come from?, why do we need to get close to A and B?"

Every real number is in between two integers.  One of them is at most $1/2$ away from it.  That's all those inequalities are saying.  Basically, we're trying to choose the Gaussian integer closest to $A+Bi$.  This is analogous to dividing $a$ by $b$ and getting $a=bq+r$, where $q$ is the integer that gets $b$ closest to $a$.  Getting $\beta\kappa$ as close as possible to $\alpha$ is crucial in ensuring that $N_{\rho}<N_{\beta}$

"Here I don't understand how the following is true"

It relates to the norm by $N_{\alpha}=|\alpha|^2$, where $||$ is the complex absolute value, which is defined as $|a+bi|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$

"why? I understand that would satisfy the expression above but it's looks weird"

We want $\alpha=\beta\kappa+\rho$, and we have the first three greek letters, so we just define $\rho$ to be $\rho=\alpha-\beta\kappa$.

Comment: The point here is that somehow we wanted to show that $N(\alpha/\beta-\kappa)<1$ right?

Comment: @TheMathNoob Technically we want $N_{\rho}<N_{\beta}$, but this follows from $N(\alpha/\beta -\kappa)<1$, yeah.  Basically, choosing $\beta\kappa$ as close to $\alpha$ as possible ensures this inequality (because of those $1/2$'s)